# Angular 1.6, $http.post not working in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, rest, firefox, spring-boot, http-post

I'm trying to make a simple Angular "$http.post" request to a basic registration REST API, but when I check the network tab (developer tools) in Firefox, the POST request is missing.

```
$http.post('http://example.com/api/user/userregistration', $scope.userInfo).then(function successCallback(response){
                 console.log(response.data.object, status);
                 $scope.processing = false;
                 $scope.processed = true;
            },function errorCallback(response){
                console.log(response.config, response.data);
            });
```

I do see a HTTP OPTIONS pre-flight request with 200 OK response, but no subsequent POST request seems to work.

I also tried making a Jquery Ajax POST request to the same API but to no avail.

The same Angular code works perfectly fine in Chrome & Safari (OSX Sierra).

I have attached the screenshot of the OPTIONS request which is returning 200 OK but the subsequent POST request is missing (no errors in console)

[image: POST request missing!]

Please help troubleshoot the above and suggest if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem and solved it.

**The problem:**

- The Firefox browser installed in my OSX machine was not showing any error, hence I was unable to troubleshoot.
- Checked the same POST request from a Firefox in Windows machine, fortunately saw an error saying:

  **Cross-origin request blocked. (Reason: invalid token "multipart/form-data" in CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers")**
- The above error means Firefox does not treat "multipart/form-data" as a valid entry in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" HTTP response header. (However, Chrome & Safari seem cool about it!)

**The Solution:**

- Removed **"multipart/form-data"** from the **"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"** HTTP response header and Voila it worked in Firefox as well!